# Xcode 6, scroll view renders different in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, swift, storyboard, ios8

I am making an app in Swift, with Xcode 6 beta 7, with base SDK iOS8. I want to build a form inside a scrollview with autolayout, and I am following [this How-to](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/ios-how-to-use-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-pure-autolayout-approach-multiple-smaller-views/).

It renders as expected in iOS 8 (simulator, both iPhone 4 and 5), but in iOS7.1 (Simulator or device) the scroll view seems to shift left, leaving no margin on the left and a bigger margin on the right, and the scroll indicator doesn't appear.

iOS8:

[image]

iOS7:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Or should I wait Apple to fix this backward compatibility issue?

Comment: I just realised that the UIAlertSheet also renders very different (worse!). Should I expect Apple to fix these issues?

Comment: Do you have constraints that connect to the container's "margin"? (And are you seeing the warning "Layout attributes relative to the layout margin on iOS versions prior to 8.0"?)

Comment: I don't see constrains that connect to the margin. I don't have the warnings that you mention neither.

I am re-building this interface and use a tableview instead, which seems to be a more iOS-ly way of building forms. I am having lots of issues with this approach.

What is really bugging me is that things like the UIActionSheet are also broken in iOS7...